# How do I obtain the info from a link in a jsp with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a requirement that states I print out a list of users to the screen. These users are all hyperlinks. When I click on one, I don't know how to determine which one got clicked and my request has nothing in it. 
Here is the particular link in the jsp:

```
<td><a style="color:red;text-align:left" href="/sponsor/manageuser.htm" target="_self">NAME</a></td>
```

How can I, with javascript, which I have little experience with, determine which NAME is clicked. There is a whole list and I have to get this one that was clicked to my controller class. When a name is clicked, it does go to my controller method, but the request has nothing in it. This is a POST method.   Please help and thanks in advance. I have to give a demo on this tomorrow.

Using Spring MVC. What I'm trying to do is get this value NAME into the implicit JSP request object so I can grab it when the form is submitted in my controller class.

Comment: Do you have jQuery or do you need a plain javascript answer?

Comment: You need to post your form code as well. If you want any data (in your case, the name to appear in your POST data), you have to submit it as part of the form.

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy Well if I'm getting the value from the link with JavaScript, how then can I get it into my request to POST? And yes, I can use jQuery if you would be willing to help. I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can add an event listener and on its handler you can access that event target and get the text content of it (in your case NAME).

So something like this will get your started

```
<td><a id="myLink" style="color:red;text-align:left" href="/sponsor/manageuser.htm" target="_self">LINK NAME</a></td>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      alert(event.target.textContent);
    });
  };
</script>
```

plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/dt71QKRNUf0cSA8XKIur?p=preview

Comment: That didn't work. I get a red line under the first parentheses that says 
"Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token"  Then also under both the pointers I get this: "Syntax error on token ">", invalid FunctionExpressionHeader". I see it works fine in your sandbox. Is there an import I should be making?

Comment: Sorry, I have an arrow function `window.onload = () => {}` which will work only with ES6: 
[ES6 Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

I changed the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dt71QKRNUf0cSA8XKIur?p=preview) and the code snippet to use ES5 `window.onload = function() {}`

Comment: Thanks, but there is a second arrow as well that my Eclipse doesn't like. The ">" after `(event)` Thanks for your help, but I need to get that variable to my Controller class. If it's in an alert, it's still on the client side. That is my next challenge. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this on an onClick handler to get the target and then you can get any data you want about the target such as the innerText attribute

```
    <script>
    function send(target) {
      console.log(target.innerText);
    }
    </script>

    <table>
    <td><a onClick="send(this)" style="color:red;text-align:left" href="#" target="_self">NAME1</a></td>
    <td><a onClick="send(this)" style="color:red;text-align:left" href="#" target="_self">NAME2</a></td>
    <td><a onClick="send(this)" style="color:red;text-align:left" href="#" target="_self">NAME3</a></td>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! This works. I can see the text in my console. But how do I get it to my controller method? It's client side and my jsp is server side. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not sure, that's kind of a vague question as I don't know what framework or what your controller looks like. If you update your question above it may help. Don't forget to vote up answers that help you either

Comment: I need that target.inner text to go in the request object that I send back to my controller method. Using Spring MVC. In your solution, it is only available in the browser-side console. How can I get it into the implicit request object in the jsp so it will be passed to the controller when the form is submitted? I hope that clears up my question. Thanks.